# Fantasy book: old wizard keeps beautiful woman prisoner

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a fantasy book 10 to 15 years ago; I remember only a few details.

There's a young red-headed girl, and I believe she's the protagonist. There's also an old wizard-type man who is keeping prisoner the "most beautiful" woman, who also has powerful magic, but is kept under spells and enchantments.

Comment: Wild guess: Jude Fisher's Fool's Gold trilogy?